# How can i get a list of all available annotations of some class

Tags: java

Is there a way I can show user a list of all available annotations related to some class , for example all annotations available with in hibernate , or under javax.persistence.

Like , to be more specific, When i write @ in Eclipse and hit CtlSpace.
I get this list http://screencast.com/t/tLAVFdi46OiB

I want to show this whole list somewhere in my application's Interface.

there must be some where this list is coming from , From where i can fetch this list .

Any idea

thanks

Comment: You have to scan *every* annotation in the classpath (so all .class files), and remember all the annotations that are applicable to a class. Eclipse has done that and cached the result for performance. You have to do it yourself for your purposes.

Comment: any idea how we do that , "scan every annotation in the classpath "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All annotations implement the [Annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html) interface. Therefore, you can try something like this to find all annotations in the `org.hibernate` package (see [Reflections javadocs](https://reflections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/reflections/javadoc/apidocs/index.html?org/reflections/Reflections.html)):

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("org.hibernate");
Set<Class<? extends Annotation>> annotations  = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Annotation.class);
```

---

You'll need the [Reflections](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections-maven/0.9.9-RC2) library, which relies on [Guava](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/18.0) and [Javassist](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javassist/javassist/3.12.1.GA). If you're using IntelliJ and gradle (which I suggest) you can include this in your gradle file:

```
compile 'org.reflections:reflections-maven:0.9.9-RC2'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
compile 'javassist:javassist:3.12.1.GA'
```

Comment: thanks , will this work for all annotations available in hibernate for example. how will i achieve that with your example. what will be the package in that scenario.

Comment: should work. not sure about the package, org.hibernate?

Comment: yeah , org.hibernate was the package , i tried that and org.hibernate.annotations as well. but getting error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Predicate,

Comment: I think that might be a separate issue. You might want to start a new SO question for that.

Comment: Its resolved, some jar was missing , And your solution works for me . Thanks !